# aws-ecs, how to add a filebeat to existing container?

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash, amazon-ecs, filebeat

I'm running web service (nginx - uwsgi) on ECS.
I'm running the two applications using supervisor.

Now I want to add another service (filebeat) which will read logs of the web servers and send to logstash on another machine.

I've been told it is good idea to separate applications (all applications run on it's own docker container and get rid of supervisor)
So I'm trying to add a `filebeat` container to the already running webserver

If I go to `define task` tab of ECS menu, it seems I'm launching a new ec2 / fargate instance, that's not what I want.
Because `filebeat` has to run on the same host as the webserver

How do I run `filebeat` docker container along with `webserver` container?

Comment: I actually have the same question. Have you checked this out? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/master/filebeat-input-docker.html